# How to efficiently add country information to documents containing coordinates in mongoDB using python?

Tags: python, mongodb, geolocation, geopy

I have a collection of check-in data from foursquare, but it doesn't have information on the country where the check-in was made, only the coordinates. I need to know the country for the model i'm helping develop, so i wrote this script that copies each document (since i don't want to mess with the original data) to another collection with this added country field.

The problem is, this runs extremely slow. I estimated that, on my personal computer, it would take around 48 days to finish. I won't be running it in my personal computer, but i'd still rather not have it take too long. If that makes any difference, the computer I intend to run this on is running mongodb version 3.4.7. If necessary, I can update it, but I would also rather not.

Is there any way to do this more efficiently, while also making sure i don't have to start from the beginning in case the program dies midway?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, ReplaceOne, errors
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

_client = MongoClient(port=27017)
_collection = cliente.large_foursquare2014.checkins.find()
documents = list()

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="omitting the name i actually used on purpose")


i = 0
j = 0
for document in _collection:
    i += 1
    if i == 1000:
        print(j)
        j += 1
        cliente.large_foursquare2014.teste.bulk_write(documents)        
        documents.clear()
        i = 0

    address = geolocator.reverse((documento['latitude'], documento['longitude'])).raw['address']
    
    document['country2'] = address['country_code'].upper()
    documents.append(ReplaceOne({'_id': document['_id']}, document, upsert=True))

    cliente.large_foursquare2014.teste.bulk_write(documents)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the MongoDB calls that are slow, because I would guess the bottleneck is the geolocator code.

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck really was the geolocator calls. performance increased by aproximately five times by changing to the reverse_geocoder package.